# JavaString declared string array returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, string

my code is rather simple so I am surprised that I cannot find the error:

```
...
<div id="TreeBoxes" style="float:right;"></div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    var trees = new Array("Ambroňe","Borovice","Břízy",...,"Zmarličníky");
    var trees_sz = trees.length;
    for(count = 0; count < trees_sz; count++) {
        var txt = document.createTextNode(trees[count]);
        document.getElementById("TreeBoxes").appendChild(txt);
    }
</script>
```

The code just creates a bunch of text saying "undefined" instead of the contents of the trees variable.
The full code is running on this site: http://www.stromytrebonska.cz/mapa/

Comment: You're provided code does not perfectly match you site's code. On your site, you are declaring a callback method. So the outer for loop counts to 41 (which is length+1), then the callback method is executed after some ajax, but the `count` is still at 41. Javascript scope strikes again.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at line 202, or `if (kml != null) {`. This is executed at the start of your callback. Take a look at the value of `count`. It's already greater than the length of your array.

Comment: @Nate thanks, I wasn't sure what exactly a callback was so I didn't spot it or think it was important to include in the question, thank you again, next time I'll know. This is my first time touching javascript.

Comment: @Nate would you have a tip as to how I could achieve what you see I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

As Diego mentioned, length is a property to you have to remove the parenthesis.

Also I'm not sure why you have that spread operator on that array. Remove it because it throws an error.

Here's a working [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexprogrammer/t3dpro83/10/)

```
var trees = new Array("Ambroňe","Borovice","Břízy", "Zmarličníky");
var trees_sz = trees.length;

console.log(trees);

for(count = 0; count < trees_sz; count++) {
   var txt = document.createTextNode(trees[count]);
   document.getElementById("TreeBoxes").appendChild(txt);
}
```

Comment: Filip put "..." to let us know that there were other strings in the array.

Comment: Indeed, there are around 40 other strings there, I figured it would clutter up the question. I was unaware that ... is a javascript operator

Comment: I knew it was something simple like that! haha Got it, sorry guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Length is not a method, is a property

```
var trees_sz = trees.length;
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo in the question on my part.